# How to make select elements shrink to max-width percent style within fieldset

Tags: html, css

When I reduce the width of my browser window, `select` elements within the `fieldset` does not reduce in size despite the `max-width` command:

```
<fieldset style="background:blue;">
<select name=countries style="max-width:90%;">
 <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

However, this works perfectly outside `fieldset` element. How do I make the `select` elements shrink to the `max-width` (percentage) within the fieldset?

**Note:** I have tested both Firefox 12.0 and Google Chrome. I am now sure that it is a cross-browser problem.

**Clarification**: Please refer to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/e2H82/) and note the difference between the behaviour of a `select` element inside a `fieldset` and another outside the `fieldset`. What I want to achieve is for the `select` element within the `fieldset` to behave like the one outside the `fieldset` element.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/J5j39/2/ . Does this not work for you on Firefox?

Comment: @waitinforatrain: nope, it didn't shrink at all when I reduce the browser window.

Comment: As far as I could see, no one had reported that Firefox bug, so I did: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=823483 Hopefully that is not a duplicate. I have not reported the corresponding Chrome/Webkit bug. Perhpas someone else would like to/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### The problem

This isn't possible, at least if you only use `max-width` (see below for solution). `<select>`s are always a [little bit tricky to style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285535/1139697), as they're [interactive content elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#interactive-content) *and* form control elements. As such, they have to follow some implicit rules. For one, you cannot make a select less wide than one of its options when using `max-width`. Think of the following scenario:

```
+------------------------------------+-+
|Another entry                       |v|
+------------------------------------+-+
|Another entry                         |
|Select box, select anything, please   |
|Another entry                         |
|Another entry                         |
+------------------------------------+-+
```

Let's say that you want to squeeze this `<select>` - what will happen? The select's width will get lesser, until...

```
+------------------------------------+-+   +-----------------------------------+-+
|Another entry                       |v|   |Another entry                      |v|
+------------------------------------+-+   +-----------------------------------+-+
|Another entry                         |   |Another entry                        | 
|Select box, select anything, please   |-->|Select box, select anything, please  | 
|Another entry                         |   |Another entry                        | 
|Another entry                         |   |Another entry                        | 
+------------------------------------+-+   +-----------------------------------+-+ 
                                                   |
           +---------------------------------------+
           v
+----------------------------------+-+   +---------------------------------+-+
|Another entry                     |v|   |Another entry                    |v|
+----------------------------------+-+   +---------------------------------+-+
|Another entry                       |   |Another entry                      | 
|Select box, select anything, please |-->|Select box, select anything, please| 
|Another entry                       |   |Another entry                      | 
|Another entry                       |   |Another entry                      | 
+----------------------------------+-+   +---------------------------------+-+
```

And then the process will stop, as the `<option>`s wouldn't fit anymore. Keep in mind that you can't style `<option>s` or at least only a little bit (color, font-variant) without getting some nasty quirks. However, the border-box can be changed, if the select is prepared correctly:

#### The solution

Use a `width` value on the `select`. Yep, it's easy as that:

```
<fieldset style="background:blue;">
 <select name=countries style="width:100%;max-width:90%;">
  <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 </select>
</fieldset>
```

Why does this work? Because the `option` will now recognize the `width` of the `select` correctly and won't force the `select` to have a implicit `min-width`. Notice that the `width` is absurd, as it is more than the `max-width`. Most browsers won't care and use the `max-width` in this case, as it provides an upper bound.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5j39/5/) (works in FF12, Chrome 18, IE9, Opera 11.60)

#### Edit

Wrapper based solution, this won't change the original width:

```
<fieldset style="background:blue;">
<div style="display:inline-block;max-width:90%;"> <!-- additional wrapper -->
 <select name=countries style="width:100%">
  <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 </select>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5j39/6/) (works in browsers listed above)

Comment: thanks for trying. I apologise if my question is not clear enough. I have added some clarification and an example in the question. Please have a look. Your proposed solution would cause the select element to expand to what is more than necessary.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this. You can use a smaller `width` (something like `45ex` should be enough). `<select>s` are always painful to style... However, I might have an idea. *edit* updated my post. You need to use an additional wrapper.

Comment: That's great! This is what I want. I have also invited two other users to help me with this question, the bounty will be yours unless they can come up better solutions. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Thanks for this insight... however, why does it behave differently when inside and outside <fieldset>? I find this inconsistency perplexing!

Comment: @iamkeir [Apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17863685/578288) `fieldset`s have legacy sizing behavior that is kept for compatibility. In Chrome, this is implemented with a default style `min-width: min-content`, and in Firefox, this is hard-coded into the rendering engine.

Comment: Your first solution initially looks broken in ie. clicking the dropdown looks like the arrow disappears and that is all. May I suggest adding a second or even third option to the JSFiddle demo: ../J5j39/5/

Comment: @DannyMahoney: Which IE version? Currently on Linux, but I can check IE later.

Comment: @Zeta I am viewing this in IE Version: 11.0.9600.18204

Comment: Looks like only the last solution from this answer works in latest version chrome, not the one above it.

Comment: Why not just make `max-width` perform like `max-width`, and `width` like width, as with all other controls? Why swap them around for just the `<select>` element only? HTML form inputs are such a pain with their inconsistencies.

Comment: In case you're asking _why_ things are specified that way, then you're probably at the wrong spot, @run_the_race. I didn't set the spec for form elements and their interaction with CSS :). (That being said, this answer is almost 11 years old, I don't quite know today's situation)

Answer (score 3):

Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5j39/4/) what you’re looking for?

```html
<fieldset style="background:blue; display:inline; width:100%;">
  <select name=countries style="width:90%;">
    <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
  </select>

  <input name=others style="display:block; min-width:300px; width:90%;">
</fieldset>
```

Either way, when you specify the width with a value (such as 300px) – this height will take priority and the element will be assigned 300px itself. Define the `width` in percentages and give the `min-width` as an absolute value. The percentage is taken from its parent element. So, you should give a percentage to its parent too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, it's not what I want. I am using max-width, not min-width, 90% so that the input element can still fit in a smartphone browser.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the select. For this example, I'll use a div with "select_wrap".

```
div.select_wrap {
  height: 1em;
} 
div.select_wrap select { 
  position: absolute;
  max-width: calc(100% - 6px);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The "absolute" context allows max-width to be interpreted - no actual position information, just force it into a different context. calc() lets you be a bit more detailed with what max-width actually should be, given you don't have margins and padding where they were previously. text-overflow looks nice.

select_wrap's height is needed to make sure the form flows around the select as expected - you need to reserve the space the select formerly filled.

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` of the `fieldset` to `100%` (or any other value)

http://jsfiddle.net/e2H82/3/

Tested in Google Chrome.

Comment: Just tested in Firefox and it doesn't fix the problem there, but it does work in Chrome.

Answer (score -4):

try:

```css
fieldset select{
    margin:auto
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.