# How to move div from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

I have a *variable height*, *100%-width* `sub-menu` which is normally positioned at the bottom of the page. I want it to be at the top of the page when viewed through a browser with a *small* window. The following is the structure of the HTML for the page:

```
<div id=container style='height: 500px; background: red;'>
 <div id=content style='width: 100%; background: green;'>content</div>
 <div id=sub-menu style='width: 100%; background: blue;'>sub-menu</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the variable height `sub-menu` to the top without blocking the content of the page using CSS?

Comment: Are you using any media queries? How are you working out if the device is a small screen?

Comment: @Sam: yes, I am using media queries with the window width as an indicator.

Comment: How are you positioning it at the bottom? With position:fixed, or with the natural flow of elements?

Comment: @eZakto: I am using the natural flow of elements for the default positioning of the menu at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you know the height of your sub-menu*, then you can do it using `position: relative` on `#container` and `position: absolute` on both your `#content` and `#sub-menu`. You'll also have to give the `#container` *a top value that's equal to the height* of your `#sub-menu`.

Comment: The problem is that the menu is dynamic, depending on which page I am on, there could be more links or less links on the menu itself.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem then. I'd say a bit of JavaScript can do the trick, but I'm really curious if anybody can come up with a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I saw your works on CSS3, quite impress with the solar system you drew. If you can't do it, I doubt others can. Would have to combine your solution with javascript then.

Comment: Would you mind helping me with [this bounty question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10672586/948920)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `display: table-header-group;`...

HTML:

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=content>content</div>
    <div id=sub-menu>sub-menu</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  display: table; 
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #sub-menu {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/lifuhavuki/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how you have your media queries set out. This might not be possible with your html structure so you may have to edit this for it to work.

```
#sub-menu
{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

The code above will need to be placed inside your media query for small screens.

Comment: As pointed out by yourself, it doesn't work without changing the html structure. The sub-menu will be blocking the content. I am looking for something that works like a float.

Comment: `position: fixed` is great, but I wouldn't use it for mobile, there are still a lot of problems - check http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the css media query solution.

```
/* Mobile Portrait Size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
height:auto; /* So that the content wont be lost with the reduction in width. */
}
```

With little more explanation of how u've placed the div or by linking it up with a fiddle would be helpful.